# Factoring explicit quantities

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I'm wondering if there is a way I can explicitly factor an equation into separate chunks. For example, if I have

```
deriv = -((E^(x3 (-etabar + zetabar)) (-etabar + zetabar) (zetabar tau[x3] - 
     I omega vbar xi[x3]))/(2 omega vbar Sqrt[zetabar])) - (
 E^(x3 (-etabar + 
     zetabar)) (-I omega vbar (c44hat tau[x3] + c64hat xi[3]) + 
    zetabar (c64hat tau[x3] + I omega v xi[x3])))/(
 2 omega vbar Sqrt[zetabar])
```

Is there a way I could obtain "deriv" in the form of

$$deriv = e^{x^3 - ...}=(\gamma_1 \xi + \gamma_2 \tau)$$

where $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are the quantities multiplying $\xi$ and $\tau$.

Comment: `Collect[deriv, {_tau, _xi}]`, I think?

Comment: You have a typo: replace `xi[3]` with `xi[x3]`.